# How to do find() with includes() in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to do something like this, but it's not working. How would I do this in Rails 3?

```
Student.find(12).includes(:teacher)
```

Answer (score 107):

You just have to be more careful with the order of the methods in this case:

```
Student.includes(:teacher).find(12)
```

Comment: Well what's it doing? You could always use the old way: `Student.find(12, :include => :teacher)`

Comment: It gets the record at id 12, but without the includes. The "old" way doesn't work in 3.0 anymore. I can get it to work this way Student.find_by_id(12).to_json( :include => :teacher) but that's not what i want

Comment: @PhilipGiuliani: the key phrase here is "in rails 3"

Answer (score 10):

Old question I know but just in case this helps someone...

Doing something like `@student = Student.includes(:teacher).where(:id => 12)` returns an array and so then using something such as `@student.id` doesn't work.

Instead you could do:

```
@student = Student.includes(:teacher).where(:id => 12).first
```

Although `Student.includes(:teacher).find(12)` should work, but you can use the `where` version if you need to search by other/multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could try "where" instead of "find":

```
Student.includes(:teacher).where(:id => 12)
```

Comment: I tried something similar on one of my models and it worked in Rails 3, are you sure you have the "belongs_to" and "has_many" relationships set up?

Comment: Yes, it's very strange b/c it work fine when I put the include in the to_json method, so it seems like everything is set up fine.